# When will Lightning components be available for Android phones?

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components

Lightning components works well with iOs whereas does not work with Android. When will this feature be available for Android?

Answer (score 3):

The same components are certified to work on Android (and most modern browsers) - can you provide more details on the specific issue(s) you have encountered when trying to use LC on Android? What version of Android (and which browser)?

Comment: I was testing through Salesforce1 App in my mobile phone. The android version is Android 4.2.2 (JellyBean).

Comment: Any update on this??

Comment: Is the issue you are reporting about the fact that your lightning component tabs do not show up in the S1 Android native application installed from google play/marketplace? I believe I misunderstood your original question.